# Deploying a HyperLedger Fabric network on HyperLedger Composer

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have created a custom hyperledger network with 2 organisations and 2 channels. I have coded the necessary .yaml files and coded an extensive GoLang file as my chaincode.

The system is working properly via the Node SDK.

What I want is the network to automatically detect the various participants, assests and transactions in the network and show a web interface just like its done in Composer Playground for the sake of a Proof of Concept.

I don't want to code all the logic again in the playgroud or create forms and then link it to my Node SDK.

Is it possible to port/link my Fabric network to Composer's web interface.